# How gas fees are calculated when minting an nft on the mainnet?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, gas

I'm working on a smart contract for minting NFTs. when I deployed it on the rinkby test network and tested the minting function, Metamask gives me 82$ as an estimation for gas fees even though it takes only 20$ when I confirm the transaction.
I think it will look scary for users to see what they don't know what to pay for, the cost of the nft is only 10$

There is any solution to show the exact gas fees to pay?

This is the mint function

```
function mint(address _account, uint256 _quantity) external payable callerIsUser{
        uint price = PRICE;
        require(price != 0, "price connot be 0");
        require((totalSupply() + _quantity) <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Y :: Beyond Max Supply");
        require(msg.value >= (PRICE * _quantity), "Y :: not enough funds ");
        _safeMint(_account, _quantity);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This happens when the tx reverts. MetaMask just sets the gas limit to the maximum allowed on Ethereum to see if that will make the tx not revert. You can use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) to debug your tx and see where it reverts.

Comment: Side node: check out [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/). There's really no reason to keep using revert reason strings in Solidity v0.8 and above. See my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94351/revert-reason-for-arithmetic-overflows-in-solidity-v0-8/102528#102528).