# Is Integer Overflow and Underflow possible in any scenerio in Solidity ^0.8.0

Tags: solidity

I came across a tweet which tells there are few scenarios in which Integer Overflow/Underflow are possible in Solidity ^0.8.0? Do you know how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revert reason for arithmetic overflows in Solidity v0.8](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94351/revert-reason-for-arithmetic-overflows-in-solidity-v0-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. If you use assembly or the `unchecked` keyword you can get an overflow/underflow.

Check this simple code I created:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Counter {

    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    function underflow_assembly() public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 n = 0;
        assembly {
            n := sub(n, 1)
        }
        // n now is equal to 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
        return n;
    }

    function underflow_unchecked() public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 n = 0;
        unchecked {
            n--;
        }
        // n now is equal to 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
        return n;
    }

    // reverts
    function no_underflow() public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint256 n = 0;
        n--;
        return n;
    }

    // reverts
    function balanceUnderflow() public {
        balances[msg.sender] -= 1;
    }

}
```

With Solidity version `^0.8.0`, you cannot get underflow/overflow unless you use the `unchecked` keyword or use assembly.